# Trigger.IO Forge error on web compile 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists'

Tags: trigger.io

this was working fine till now but suddenly i got this error everytime on trigger toolkit while trying to forge as a web application

```
[ERROR] [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: u'development\\web'
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this before on Windows. It has to do with the OS not being able to delete the folders for the last working environment. While I don't know why this happens, I can fix it by navigating to the /development folder and removing the /web folder. Once removed, you can run the process.